# Serialization of local class returned from Callable

Tags: java, exception, serialization, anonymous-class, callable

This is a brainscratcher.

I know this actual code is horrible on so many levels. My question is not *how* to do this (I know about static initialization blocks), but *why* this doesn't work, for the benefit of my  understanding of Java serialization.

Why does this work

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Main {

    static Comparator<String> COMPARE_STRING_LENGTH;
    static {
        class CompareStringReverse implements Comparator<String>, Serializable {
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.length() - o2.length();
            }
        };
        COMPARE_STRING_LENGTH = new CompareStringReverse();    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.ser"));
        out.writeObject(new TreeSet<String>(COMPARE_STRING_LENGTH));
        out.close();
    }

}
```

while this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

class Main {

    static Comparator<String> COMPARE_STRING_LENGTH = new Callable<Comparator<String>>() {
        public Comparator<String> call() {
            class CompareStringReverse implements Comparator<String>, Serializable {
                public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                    return o1.length() - o2.length();
                }
            };
            return new CompareStringReverse();
        }
    }.call();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.ser"));
        out.writeObject(new TreeSet<String>(COMPARE_STRING_LENGTH));
        out.close();
    }

}
```

yields

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: Main$1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well the "why" is slightly subtle. Even though your *named* class (`CompareStringReverse`) implements `Serializable`, it's nested within an *anonymous* class which doesn't. It's therefore an inner class, and has an implicit reference to an instance of the enclosing anonymous class. For example, if you run:

```
javap -c Main$1$1CompareStringReverse
```

You'll see the field:

```
final Main$1 this$0;
```

That's what's failing to be serialized. You can still fix it easily though:

```
interface SerializableCallable<T> extends Serializable, Callable<T> {}

...

static Comparator<String> COMPARE_STRING_LENGTH = 
    new SerializableCallable<Comparator<String>>() {
       ...
};
```

The only significant difference is that the anonymous class now implements `Serializable` as well as `Callable<T>`. I don't *think* there's any way of specifying multiple interfaces for an anonymous class to implement (i.e. you do have to create the extra interface to combine the two) but I could be wrong.

So now the named inner class implements `Serializable`, and so does the type of its sole field, so everything works.

Comment: Actually, I suppose I mistitled this, since my classes are not really "anonymous" since they have the have the name "CompareStringReverse", but they already **do** implement Serializable.

Comment: @PaulDraper: Ah, missed that - but it's an *inner* class within an anonymous class, which means there's an implicit reference to an instance of the anonymous class. Will experiment just to validate, then edit.

Comment: @PaulDraper: Right. The cause was right, but one level removed... which explains why the solution worked too :) See my edited answer for the full explanation - and obviously let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: You're right. I defined my own Callable interface that extends Serializable, and it worked. It was the implicit reference to the non-serializable outer class that cause it.

Comment: And yes, there is no way to have an anonymous class implement two interfaces.